# Comparison operators for C strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, comparison

I am having some difficulty locating information of comparing C strings. I understand that unlike C++, C does not support operator overloading, so I'm wondering if there is any way to check if one string is greater/less than another (e.g. str1 > str2)?

Thanks ahead of time for your responses. This is honestly one of the first times I have actually had to ask a question because I could not find a related post.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several, each serving different purposes (omitting wide character variants for now).

[`strcmp`](http://man.he.net/man3/strcmp) – compares two strings, character by character (with the C notion of what strings are equal or not – that doesn't need to coincide with how humans think – see `strcoll`). There's a variant for comparing only the first at most *n* characters, `strncmp`.

[`strcasecmp`](http://man.he.net/man3/strcasecmp) – compares two strings, ignoring case. There's a variant for comparing only the first at most *n* characters, `strncasecmp`.

[`strcoll`](http://man.he.net/man3/strcoll) – compares two strings, observing the currently set locale (which is why it's called collation, not comparing in this case). If you want `ss` and `ß` to compare equal for a German audience, then this is what you should use.

---

Where you might write

```
if (string1 > string2) ...
```

in a language, you have to write

```
if (strmp(string1, string2) > 0) ...
```

in C. Essentially you move both operands into the function call, retain the comparison operator and compare with `0` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Use strcmp() in C.

for example if you want to compare two strings s1 and s2 then,

strcmp(s1,s2) will return 0 if they are equal, positive integer if s1 is greater than s2 and negative integer if s1 is lesser  than s2.