# Trying to create simple C program to edit 1 line in a text file

Tags: c, file-io

I am trying to create a C executable that will just toggle a line in my hosts file.

e.g. changing this:

```
74.125.224.72 asdf.com www.asdf.com
```

to this:

```
#74.125.224.72 asdf.com www.asdf.com
```

And back.

This is to make it easier to switch between a development version of a website and the live version.
I managed to figure out how to append to the file, but I'm having problems comparing each line to the line I'm searching for, and I also don't know how to replace a line in the file. The test program I'm pasing below edits "test.txt" on my desktop.  I cannot get the string matching in the while loop to match anything.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLINE 50
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *ifp, *ofp;

    ifp = fopen("C:/Users/Buttle/Desktop/test.txt","a+");
    if (ifp == NULL) {
        printf("Dang it didn't work!\n");
    }

    else printf("Dang it did work!\n");

    char line[MAXLINE];

    int linnum = 1;
    while ((fgets(line,MAXLINE,ifp) != NULL)) {
        printf("line number %d\n" , linnum++);      
        if (line == "74.125.224.72") {
            fputs("#74.125.224.72 asdf.com www.asdf.com",stdout);
        } else if (line == "#74.125.224.72"){
            fputs("74.125.224.72 asdf.com www.asdf.com",stdout);
        } else fputs("We ain't found sh--.",ifp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this earlier question on [Comparison operators for C strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890970/comparison-operators-for-c-strings)

Comment: seems it would be easier to just have two copies of hosts and just copy the files to hosts with a batch file?

Comment: Are you forced to use C? It *might* be easier using some scripting language, such as Python...

Comment: @AndersK I'm open to any kind of solution. This is just what I tried first.

Comment: @phimuemue I would be fine doing it in Python but I would want to figure out how to make it an .exe that I can just send. I'm actually writing this primarily for someone else. I want them to be able to click the exe to toggle the value. With Python wouldn't I have to package Python into the exe somehow?

Answer (score 2):

At first, you'll need two files (or you'll have to implement buffer to read it all. So:

```cpp
ifp = fopen("C:/Users/Buttle/Desktop/test.txt","r"); // Why use a+?
ofp = fopen("C:/Users/Buttle/Desktop/test.txt","w"); // Or use output to std
```

And let's make it more general for you:

```cpp
// This will contain list of all ips that you want to handle
typedef const char * cstr;
cstr blacklist[] = {
    "1.2.3.4",
    "5.6.7.8",
    NULL
};


int i;
unsigned char comment; // This is bool
while ((fgets(line,MAXLINE,ifp) != NULL)) {
    i = 0;
    comment = 0;
    while( blacklist[i] != NULL){
        if( strncmp( blacklist[i], line, strlen( blacklist[i]) == 0){
             comment = 1;
             break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    if( comment){
        fprintf( ofp, "#%s\n", line);
    } else {
        fprintf( ofp, "%s\n", line);
    }
}
```

*You may need to include several header files, but I hope you'll be able to google it :)*

Answer (score 0):

```
char line[MAXLINE];
```

represents an array. `line` corresponds to the memory address from where the array starts.

You are comparing `line` to `"74.125.224.72"`, it's wrong. Strings cannot be compared this way.

You need to use something like this:

```
if (strcmp(line, "74.125.224.72") == 0) ... // return 0 if are same
```

From the manpage:

> **int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);**
>
> The  strcmp()  function  compares the two strings s1 and s2.  It returns an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if s1
>   is found, respectively, to be less
>          than, to match, or be greater than s2.

Comment: @Bart Someone commented already in the question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890970/comparison-operators-for-c-strings. That's why, I didn't write.

Comment: You have "strmp" and I think you meant "strcmp"

Comment: @ButtleButkus Yeah. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Your substring search is wrong!  The condition `if (line == "74.125.224.72")`  must be replaced  with something like :

```
if ( (strncmp("74.125.224.72", line, strlen("74.125.224.72")) == 0 )
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it always for the same file, always for the same line, I'd try a different approach:

Write the line in question with a leading space and find the position of that space in the file. Then just update it ...

```
#define CONFIG_FILE "hosts"
#define FIXED_POSITION 605

    handle = fopen(CONFIG_FILE, "r+b");
    fseek(handle, FIXED_POSITION, SEEK_SET);
    fputc(DEVELOPMENT ? '#' : ' ', handle);
    fclose(handle);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if leading space would be allowed in the hosts file, but I might give this a try and see.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINE 100
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *ifp, *ofp;

    ifp = fopen("C:/Users/Buttle/Desktop/test.txt","r");
    if (ifp == NULL) {
         printf("Dang it didn't work!\n");
    }
    else printf("Dang it did work!\n");

    char line[MAXLINE];

    int linnum = 1;
    if(fscanf(ifp,"%s",line) != NULL) {           
        printf("line number %d\n" , linnum++ );                    
        if (strcmp(line, "74.125.224.72")==0 ) {                         
            fputs("#74.125.224.72 asdf.com www.asdf.com",stdout);
            //fputs("#74.125.224.72 asdf.com www.asdf.com",ifp);
        } else if (strcmp(line, "#74.125.224.72")==0 ){
            fputs("74.125.224.72 asdf.com www.asdf.com",stdout);
           // fputs("#74.125.224.72 asdf.com www.asdf.com",ifp);
        } else fputs("We ain't found sh--.",stdout);
        //else fputs("We ain't found sh--.",ifp);

    }

    fclose(ifp);
    return 0;
}
```

i think this will help

Answer (score -1):

My friend helped me come up with a solution, so I'll post it here. The strangest thing is I tried in on a couple of different Windows 7 installations and it worked slightly differently. On mine, it only works if I run it by right-clicking and selecting "Run as Administrator", whereas on another installation, a simple double-click works. That's unexpected because the hosts file should be protected by the operating system.

My friend wanted to do it without using any built-in functions (just for a challenge) but I think I inserted a couple myself.

This answer is by far the longest one, probably because it is the worst-written. I'll look at the other ones before picking the best.

Here it is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FILENAME "C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts"
//#define FILENAME "asdf.txt"

int finder(char * Old_String, char * Find_String);
char * replacer(int replace_point, char * Old_String, char * Replace_String, int find_length);

int finder(char * Old_String, char * Find_String)
{
    //printf("\nOld String: \n%s \n\n\n", Old_String);
    //printf("\nFind String: \n%s \n\n\n", Find_String);
    int old_length = strlen(Old_String);
    int find_length = strlen(Find_String);
    //int replace_length = strlen(Replace_String);
    if (old_length == 0) printf("Old String is empty");
    if (find_length == 0) printf("Find String is empty");
    //if (replace_length == 0) printf("Replace String is empty");
    int replace_point = 0;
    while (replace_point < old_length)
    {
        if ((Old_String[replace_point] == Find_String[0]) && (old_length - replace_point >= find_length))
        {
            int compare_point = 0;
            int This_Found = 1;
            while (compare_point < find_length)
            {
                if (Old_String[replace_point + compare_point] != Find_String[compare_point]) This_Found = 0;
                compare_point ++;
            }
            if (This_Found == 1) break;
        }
        replace_point ++;
    }
    if (replace_point == old_length) return -1;
    else return replace_point;
}

char * replacer(int replace_point, char * Old_String, char * Replace_String, int find_length)
{
    int before_length = replace_point;
    int old_length = strlen(Old_String);
    int replace_length = strlen(Replace_String);
    int after_length = old_length - before_length - find_length;
    int new_length = before_length + replace_length + after_length;
    char * Before_String = (char *) malloc(before_length);
    char * After_String = (char *) malloc(after_length);
    char * New_String = (char *) malloc(new_length);
    memcpy(Before_String, Old_String, before_length);
    memcpy(After_String, Old_String + before_length + find_length, after_length);
    memcpy(New_String, Before_String, before_length);
    memcpy(New_String + before_length, Replace_String, replace_length);
    memcpy(New_String + before_length + replace_length, After_String, after_length);
    return New_String;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char * Find_String = "#74.125.224.72 asdf.com www.asdf.com";
    char * Replace_String = "74.125.224.72 asdf.com www.asdf.com";
    char * New_String;
    char * Output_Msg;
    int find_length = strlen(Find_String);
    FILE * ifp = fopen(FILENAME, "r+");
    int old_string_length = 0;
    while(getc(ifp) != EOF) old_string_length ++;
    char * Old_String = (char *) malloc(old_string_length);
    fseek(ifp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    for (int i = 0; i < old_string_length; i++) Old_String[i] = getc(ifp);
    fclose(ifp);
    ifp = fopen(FILENAME, "w");

    int replace_point = finder(Old_String, Find_String);
    if(replace_point != -1)
    {
        New_String = replacer(replace_point, Old_String, Replace_String, find_length);
        Output_Msg = "\nSwitched to NEW VERSION (development version)\n\nIn your browser, while at www.asdf.com,\n\npress CTRL+F5 and/or F5 to refresh the page.\n\nYou may have to repeat F5 and/or CTRL+F5 several times.\n\n";       
    }
    else if(replace_point == -1)
    {
        Find_String = "74.125.224.72 asdf.com www.asdf.com";
        Replace_String = "#74.125.224.72 asdf.com www.asdf.com";
        find_length = strlen(Find_String);
        replace_point = finder(Old_String, Find_String);
        New_String = replacer(replace_point, Old_String, Replace_String, find_length);
        Output_Msg = "\nSwitched to OLD VERSION (production version)\n\nIn your browser, while at www.asdf.com,\n\npress CTRL+F5 and/or F5 to refresh the page.\n\nYou may have to repeat F5 and/or CTRL+F5 several times.\n\n";
    }

    if (New_String == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nError: Replace function returned NULL. Exiting... \n");
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    //printf("\nNew String: \n%s \n\n\n", New_String);
    fseek(ifp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    int i = 0;
    while(New_String[i] != '\0')
    {
        putc(New_String[i], ifp);
        i ++;
    }
    fclose(ifp);
    printf(Output_Msg);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```